# Extract descendant LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Struggling in vain to extract the value of the **Status** descendant from an XML file generated via the Azure REST API using XDocument (LINQ to XML). No issues extracting root elements using this method:

```
var hsname = xmldoc.Root.Element(ns + "ServiceName").Value;
```

Getting the descendants is proving to be a nightmare.  Abbreviated XML file below - please help :-)

```
-<HostedService xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
    <Url>https://management.core.windows.net/subscriptionID/services/hostedservices/hostedservicename</Url>
    <ServiceName><hostedservicename></ServiceName>
        -<HostedServiceProperties>
            <Description/>
            <Location>South Central US</Location>
            <Label>EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</Label>
        </HostedServiceProperties>
        -<Deployments>
            -<Deployment>
            <Name>DeploymentName</Name>
            <DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot>
            <PrivateID>55555555555555555555</PrivateID>
            <Status>Running</Status>
```

Comment: Why using LINQ to XML? If you have XML schema, you can generate code which automatically parses the XML.

[XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown what you've tried... but I'd expect this to be fine:

```
string status = (string) xmldoc.Descendants(ns + "Status").FirstOrDefault();
```

That will give you a null value if there are no `Status` elements. You may want to use `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()` etc depending on your requirements.

EDIT: Just to expand on the comment, you can make your code more robust in the face of other `Status` elements like this:

```
string status = (string) xmldoc.Descendants(ns + "HostedService")
                               .Descendants(ns + "ServiceName")
                               .Descendants(ns + "Deployments")
                               .Descendants(ns + "Deployment")
                               .Descendants(ns + "Status")
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @mynameisneo: consider that using this snippet of code is returning you the value of the first occurrence of an "Status" Descendant. look closely at the schema to verfiy that no other "Status"-Element can occure before.

Comment: @hacktick: That's fine, because I'm specifying the hostedservicename, which is unique, and I'll use the same method to filter out only Production deployments